# Verify yum repo for a application

Tags: shell, yum

Can we verify yum repo before installing any application using shell script .

Need to verify 2 things

1.The connectivity from server to yum repo

2.All the dependency available on the repo and can be installed .

```
I found a command **yum install package_name --assumeno**
```

But the exist status of command is **1** always . Is there any other command for the above requirement for dry installation and get exit status .

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for my question . We can use " **yum install --downloadonly** "
option to connect the repo and download the application without installing .

reference:- [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-downloadonly-plugin/)